How to convert gb_trees to json?
Is there an efficient way to convert gb_trees to json in erlang or maps? Here is a truncated example:
{46,
                 {{25,56},
                  {fld,{25,56},0},
                  {{25,30},
                   {fld,{25,30},nil},
                   {{25,11},
                    {fld,{25,11},0},

I would like to convert this type of tree into json for transmission to another application.

I'm not sure how you ended up with that tree.
It seems that the structure is incomplete, anyway (IIUC, that tree should have 46 entries in total and you're showing 3 or 4 of them).
In any case, this is an example of how to convert a gb_tree into a map and then encode it as json:
1> ATree = gb_trees:from_orddict([{k_a,v_a}, {k_b,v_b}, {k_c,v_c}]).
{3,{k_b,v_b,{k_a,v_a,nil,nil},{k_c,v_c,nil,nil}}}
2> AMap = maps:from_list(gb_trees:to_list(ATree)).
#{k_a => v_a,k_b => v_b,k_c => v_c}
3> AJson = json:encode(AMap).
["{",
 [[34,<<"k_a">>,34],58,34,<<"v_a">>,34],
 [[44,[34,<<"k_b">>,34],58,34,<<"v_b">>,34],
  [44,[34,<<"k_c">>,34],58,34,<<"v_c">>,34]],
 "}"]
4> io:format("~ts~n", [AJson]).
{"k_a":"v_a","k_b":"v_b","k_c":"v_c"}
ok

Hope this helps.

your example will work, but I have keys like {20, 30} and values ​​like {fld , {20 , 30}, [ ]}.will require additional transformations either in the tree before converting to a list, or after converting to maps.I haven't found a way to check that my structure is a tree. I will need to go around the tree that contains the tree.

So... you're not using gb_trees, you have your own structure?

Of course I use it, but my tree value may be a record containing a tree. After looking at the library sources, I understood how to check whether I have a tree or not. I didn't do the code, I'm just working through the code. I was able to convert the tree to Map
